# Cut out a city in a map based on (a path) administrative boundries

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, maps, path-effects

[image]I want to cut out this city, from a map, based on the yellow dotted line (administratieve boundries). So what is within the yellow line I want to remain and what is out off the line I want to delete. Does somebody know an easy way to cut this at ones in Illustrator?

I will add the files here!

Kr,

Freddy

Ps. I cannot upload the SVG so I did a We transfer link https://we.tl/t-fktjiplJ9H

Comment: why don't you just delete the elements outside of the boundaries? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to group the artwork, then draw a path with the Pen Tool to define the area you want to cut out, then select both artwork and path, and do *Object > Clipping Mask > Make*.

If you want to retain the outline, copy it before applying the clipping mask, then apply the clipping mask, then do *Edit > Paste in Place* to get the outline back. Apply a stroke colour and dash.

Answer (score 0):

You have already got a visually perfect receipe (by Mr.Kerr). Many of us like to evaporate the parts which are not any more visible under the clipping mask. If you have taken for ex. a snippet from OpenStreetMap there can easily be 5000% unwanted stuff hanging around, the clipping mask makes it only invisible but it's there making the machine slower and appearing now and then as a ghost when the mouse hovers over it.

One workaround exists. This can be done after you are sure no map data edits are any more needed.

1. Select your map, apply Object > Expand > objects+strokes+fills. Group the map.
2. Draw the clipping border. Lift it to the front if it already is there somewhere under the other stuff. Have a copy of the border if you need it later, lock it or keep it in the clipboard.
3. Select the border and the underlying group. Apply Pathfinder panel's Crop.

The extras vanish permanently. You get a map which contains a group of closed filled paths with no strokes. It's very hard to edit, but not impossible.

Comment: Note that this may not end up saving a lot because the closed paths are slower to render and expanding and cropping creates more complex paths so it makes the date more than double in size